# How to refuse a Clearxchange payment?

Tags: online-payment, receipt

A client sent me a payment via Clearxchange. 
I do not use Clearxchange, nor do I want to start using it.

The website states that once a payment is sent, then the sender cannot cancel it.

But there is no information I can find about being able to refuse a payment and thereby return the money to the client.

This is a good client, we have a good relationship. I want to help him help me. If I can't get around it, then I'll just suck it up, give Clearexchange the minimum data I must to get payment, and then cancel it.

But if there's a cleaner, easier way to do it, then that's my preference.

Note: I do realize that I could call Clearxchange and talk to one of their peeps, but would prefer to not have to deal with what I anticipate will surely be attempts to sign me up.

Comment: really the best answer is **politerly**.  I would just tell your nice client "Ah, we cannot accept those in my country XYZ, you'll have to take it back and make a normal payment".  OK?  (So, it's "you" that cannot accept them, and, you're in country XYZ  :)  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your bank* uses ClearXchange, not you. It is not a website where you open an account, like many others, but an inter-bank transfer system based on email addresses, kind of like free wire transfers between everyone.

You don't have to set anything up, just accept the payment, and the money appears in your account (assuming the client used the email address your bank has on file for you).

However, if you still don't want it, you can just ignore it. There is a timeout when his transaction gets auto-cancelled, and he gets his money back.

Here is an example text from the 'fine print' (my highlighting): "*[...]We will continue our attempts by sending a second notice of a transfer to the recipient, and providing the recipient a period of **nine (9) succeeding Business Days** to register in the Service, or the person-to-person payment service of clearXchange, Zelle or a Network Bank. At the end of this period, if the recipient still has not registered, the transfer request **will be Cancelled**. The sender **may cancel the transfer at any time** during this ten (10) day period **if the recipient is not registered** at the time of cancellation.[...]*" (https://chaseonline.chase.com/Public/Misc/LAContent.aspx?agreementKey=chasenet_la)

Comment: Aganju - your answer helped me understand how clearxchange worked, and when I saw the link to Chase, I investigated how it worked with my bank and several others for transfers, fees, and other actions I needed to think about. It appears that each bank has its own rules for sending or receiving money with clearxchange.